# How to make a row editable on click of a button in React bootstrap table?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I want to make a row editable in a react bootstrap table on click of a button, how can I do it, I am new to React.

Comment: Could you post your code to show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Without any sample code, it's not easy to provide a full working example but only a suggestion:

What I would try to do: 
in constructor:

```
this.state = { isEditable: false }
```

in onClick of button:

```
this.setState({ isEditable: true })
```

in table you should set the editable field (if this is exists, this is why I need sample code) to the state isEditable field

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using `readOnly` property of input and change it with `onFocus`.

```
<input type="text"
 className="form-control"
 value={this.state.value}
 onChange={this.ChangeValue}
 onFocus={this.EditValue}
 readOnly={this.state.boolean}
 />
```

and in the `EditValue` function:

```
    EditValue=()=>{this.setState({boolean:true})}
```